# SQL max and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with data like:

```
name   |  size
name1  |  3.16
name1  |  3.14
name2  |  2.85
name3  |  2.14
name3  |  2.02
```

And I execute my query `select name, max(size) from table GROUP BY name, size order by size desc limit 1000;`

I'm expecting query will returns:
`name1 3.16; name2 2.85; name3 2.14` but instead I got all records in DB. Tell me please where I'm wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accompish?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm trying to get max size for each name. lad2025 give answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the column size form group by cluase
use   group by name only

```
select name, max(size) 
from table GROUP BY name

order by max(size) desc limit 1000;
```

each column name in group by clause is use for aggregation break

Comment: If I delete size from `group by` clause I getting error: ''column size must appear in the group by clause'

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit first:

```
SELECT name, max(size) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY size DESC LIMIT 1000) s
GROUP BY name;
```